# How to create UI Control with many complex type

Tags: xpages

I still trying around about UI Control like this post :
[How to create group property on xsp-config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614189/how-to-create-group-property-on-xsp-config)

Now I get some problem when I try to include collection of child complex type into another collection of complex type.

I want to have properties like this :

> - navigation
> - menu(+)(-)
>
>   - menu[0] // for dropdown, please look menu[0] below
>   - menu[1]

And each menu has child properties like this :

> - menu[0]
>
>   - link
>   - icon
>   - name
>   - submenu(+)(-)
>   - submenu[0] // for dropdown please look submenu[0] below
>   - submenu[1]
> - menu[1]
>
>   - link
>   - icon
>   - name

And last.. here properties of submenu

> - submenu[0]
>
>   - link
>   - name
> - submenu[1]
>
>   - link
>   - name

And here my script of that component and complex type

```
// 1. NAVIGATION COMPONENT 
package com.forte.component;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.el.ValueBinding;

import com.forte.complex.Menu;
import com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil;

public class ForteNavigation extends UIComponentBase {
    public static final String RENDERER_TYPE = "com.forte.Navigation";
    private String navigation;
    private Menu menu;

public ForteNavigation() {
    super();
    setRendererType(RENDERER_TYPE);
}
@Override
public String getFamily() {
    return RENDERER_TYPE;
}

// NAVIGATION
public String getNavigation() {
    if (null != this.navigation) {
        return this.navigation;
    }
    ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("navigation");
    if (_vb != null) {
        return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    }
    return null;
}   
public void setNavigation(String navigation){
    this.navigation = navigation;
}

// MENU
public Menu getMenu() {
    if (null != this.menu) {
        return this.menu;
    }
    ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("menu");
    if (_vb != null) {
        return (Menu) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    }
    return null;
}   
public void setMenu(Menu menu){
    this.menu = menu;
}

@Override   
public void restoreState(FacesContext _context, Object _state) {
    Object _values[] = (Object[]) _state;
    super.restoreState(_context, _values[0]);
    this.navigation = (String) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, this, _values[1]);         
    this.menu = (Menu) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, this, _values[2]);         
}

@Override
public Object saveState(FacesContext _context) {
    Object _values[] = new Object[3];
    _values[0] = super.saveState(_context);
    _values[1] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, navigation);
    _values[2] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, menu);
    return _values;
}   
}


// 2. MENU COMPLEX TYPE
package com.forte.complex;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.el.ValueBinding;
import com.ibm.xsp.complex.ValueBindingObjectImpl;
import com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil;

public class Menu extends ValueBindingObjectImpl {
    private String icon;
    private String link;
    private Boolean visible;
    private String name;
    private SubMenu subMenu;

    public Menu() {

    }

    // ICON
    public String getIcon() {
        if (null != this.icon) {
            return this.icon;
        }
        ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("icon");
        if (_vb != null) {
            return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public void setIcon(String icon){
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    // LINK
    public String getLink() {
        if (null != this.link) {
            return this.link;
        }
        ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("link");
        if (_vb != null) {
            return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public void setLink(String link){
        this.link = link;
    }

    // VISIBLE
    public Boolean getVisible() {
        if (null != this.visible) {
            return this.visible;
        }
        ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("visible");
        if (_vb != null) {
            return (Boolean) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public void setVisible(boolean visible){
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    // NAME
    public String getName() {
        if (null != this.name) {
            return this.name;
        }
        ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("name");
        if (_vb != null) {
            return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    // ICON
    public Object getSubMenu() {
        if (null != this.subMenu) {
            return this.subMenu;
        }
        ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("subMenu");
        if (_vb != null) {
            return (Object) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public void setSubMenu(SubMenu subMenu){
        this.subMenu = subMenu;
    }

    @Override   
    public void restoreState(FacesContext _context, Object _state) {
        Object _values[] = (Object[]) _state;
        super.restoreState(_context, _values[0]);
        this.icon = (String) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, getComponent(), _values[1]);
        this.link = (String) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, getComponent(), _values[2]);
        this.visible = (Boolean) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, getComponent(), _values[3]);
        this.name = (String) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, getComponent(), _values[4]);
        this.subMenu = (SubMenu) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, getComponent(), _values[5]);
    }

    @Override
    public Object saveState(FacesContext _context) {
        Object _values[] = new Object[6];
        _values[0] = super.saveState(_context);
        _values[1] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, icon);        
        _values[2] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, link);
        _values[3] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, visible);
        _values[4] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, name);
        _values[5] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, subMenu);     
        return _values;
    }   

 }


 // 3. SUBMENU COMPLEX TYPE

 package com.forte.complex;

 import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
 import javax.faces.el.ValueBinding;

 import com.ibm.xsp.complex.ValueBindingObjectImpl;
 import com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil;

 public class SubMenu extends ValueBindingObjectImpl  {
    private String link;
    private Boolean visible;
    private String name;

    public SubMenu() {
    }

    // LINK
    public String getLink() {
        if (null != this.link) {
            return this.link;
        }
        ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("link");
        if (_vb != null) {
            return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public void setLink(String link){
        this.link = link;
    }

    // VISIBLE
    public Boolean getVisible() {
        if (null != this.visible) {
            return this.visible;
        }
        ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("visible");
        if (_vb != null) {
            return (Boolean) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public void setVisible(Boolean visible){
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    // NAME
    public String getName() {
        if (null != this.name) {
            return this.name;
        }
        ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("name");
        if (_vb != null) {
            return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override   
    public void restoreState(FacesContext _context, Object _state) {
        Object _values[] = (Object[]) _state;
        super.restoreState(_context, _values[0]);
        this.link = (String) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, getComponent(), _values[2]);
        this.visible = (Boolean) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, getComponent(), _values[3]);
        this.name = (String) FacesUtil.objectFromSerializable(_context, getComponent(), _values[4]);
    }

    @Override
    public Object saveState(FacesContext _context) {
        Object _values[] = new Object[4];
        _values[0] = super.saveState(_context);
        _values[1] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, link);
        _values[2] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, visible);
        _values[3] = FacesUtil.objectToSerializable(_context, name);
        return _values;
    }   

 }


 // LAST.. NAVIGATION.XSP-CONFIG
<faces-config>
  <faces-config-extension>
    <namespace-uri>http://fortedynamic.org/xsp/control</namespace-uri>
    <default-prefix>forte</default-prefix>
  </faces-config-extension>

  <component>
    <description>Forte Navigation</description>
    <display-name>Navigation</display-name>
    <component-type>com.forte.Navigation</component-type>
    <component-class>com.forte.component.ForteNavigation</component-class>
    <component-extension>
      <component-family>com.forte.Navigation</component-family>
      <renderer-type>com.forte.Navigation</renderer-type>
      <tag-name>navigation</tag-name>
        <designer-extension>
         <in-palette>true</in-palette>
         <category>Forte Smart UI</category>
                 <render-markup>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&#xd;
&lt;xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xp_1="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"&gt;&#xd;  
    &lt;xp:radioGroup layout="&lt;%=
      this.navigation=='left'?'pageDirection':'lineDirection'
    %&gt;"  style="width:155px;height:27px" &gt;    
    &lt;xp:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;%=
      this.navigation=='left'?'Left Navigation':' '
    %&gt;" &gt;&lt;/xp:selectItem&gt;
    &lt;xp:selectItem itemLabel=" "&gt;&lt;/xp:selectItem&gt;
    &lt;xp:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;%=
      this.navigation=='left'?' ':'Top Navigation'
    %&gt;" &gt;&lt;/xp:selectItem&gt;

    &lt;/xp:radioGroup&gt;
&lt;/xp:view&gt;</render-markup>
        </designer-extension>
    </component-extension>

<property>
  <description>Navigation</description>
  <display-name>Navigation</display-name>
  <property-name>navigation</property-name>
  <property-class>string</property-class>
  <property-extension>
    <designer-extension>
      <category>forte</category>
      <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
      <editor-parameter>top&#xd;
      left&#xd;
      </editor-parameter>
    </designer-extension>
  </property-extension>
</property>

<property>
    <description>Menu</description>
    <display-name>Menu</display-name>
    <property-name>menu</property-name>
    <property-class>java.util.List</property-class>
    <property-extension>
        <allow-run-time-binding>false</allow-run-time-binding>
        <collection-property>true</collection-property>
        <property-item-class>com.forte.complex.Menu</property-item-class>
        <property-add-method>addMenu</property-add-method>
        <designer-extension>
            <category>forte</category>
       </designer-extension>
    </property-extension>
</property>

  </component>


<complex-type>
    <description>Menu</description>
    <display-name>Menu</display-name>
    <complex-id>com.forte.complex.menu</complex-id>
    <complex-class>com.forte.complex.Menu</complex-class>
    <property-extension>
        <container-class>java.util.Collection</container-class>
        <collection-property>true</collection-property>
      </property-extension> 
    <property>
      <property-name>icon</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>link</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>name</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
        <property-name>visible</property-name>
        <property-class>boolean</property-class>
        <property-extension>
          <designer-extension>
            <editor>com.ibm.std.BooleanCheckBox</editor>
          </designer-extension>
        </property-extension>
      </property>

     <property>
        <property-name>submenu</property-name>
        <property-class>java.util.List</property-class>
        <property-extension>
            <allow-run-time-binding>false</allow-run-time-binding>
            <collection-property>true</collection-property>
            <property-item-class>com.forte.complex.SubMenu</property-item-class>
            <property-add-method>addSubMenu</property-add-method>
        </property-extension>
    </property>
    <complex-extension>
        <tag-name>menu</tag-name>
    </complex-extension>
</complex-type>


<complex-type>
    <description>Sub Menu</description>
    <display-name>Sub Menu</display-name>
    <complex-id>com.forte.complex.submenu</complex-id>
    <complex-class>com.forte.complex.SubMenu</complex-class>
    <property-extension>
        <container-class>java.util.Collection</container-class>
        <collection-property>true</collection-property>
      </property-extension> 
    <property>
      <property-name>link</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>name</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>      
    <property>
        <property-name>visible</property-name>
        <property-class>boolean</property-class>
        <property-extension>
          <designer-extension>
            <editor>com.ibm.std.BooleanValue</editor>
          </designer-extension>
        </property-extension>
      </property>

    <complex-extension>
        <tag-name>submenu</tag-name>
    </complex-extension>
</complex-type>

</faces-config>
```

And when I try to save after add that UI Control (with menu and submenu) to index.xsp. An Error occurs with prompt like this :

```
Could not generate a .java file for the page /index.xsp: Could not find a method for the collection property <submenu> on the object <menu>, to add the value <submenu>.    index.xsp   testing.nsf/XPages  line 1  XPages Problem
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the source code of the application layout control in the XPages extension library? It pretty much does implement exactly such a structure (you might find that it is actually what you need).

Comment: Thanks Wissel.. I have solved my problem with addSubMenu method in complex java file. And can you give me some advice where I can find full documentation about how to create UI Control XPAGES ? Like how to binding UI Control with eventHandler, etc. And I just found article about create Basic UI Control and that article doesn't explain about binding with EventHandlers.

Comment: Add your solution as answer to your question. SO lives from giving back. Check out the XPages books afaik they cover all of it. And again the Extlib sources are quite enlightening

Comment: Thanks for your advice. And I also add my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I post my answer of this question :

```
// COMPLEX MENU.JAVA
package com.forte.complex;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.el.ValueBinding;
import com.ibm.xsp.complex.ValueBindingObjectImpl;
import com.ibm.xsp.util.StateHolderUtil;

public class Menu extends ValueBindingObjectImpl {
        private String id;
        private String icon;
        private String link;
        private String target;
        private Boolean visible;
        private String name;
        private List<SubMenu> subMenu;

        public Menu() {

        }

        // ID
        public String getId() {
            if (null != this.id) {
                return this.id;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("id");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setId(String id){
            this.id = id;
        }

        // ICON
        public String getIcon() {
            if (null != this.icon) {
                return this.icon;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("icon");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setIcon(String icon){
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        // LINK
        public String getLink() {
            if (null != this.link) {
                return this.link;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("link");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setLink(String link){
            this.link = link;
        }

        // TARGET
        public String getTarget() {
            if (null != this.target) {
                return this.target;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("target");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setTarget(String target){
            this.target = target;
        }


        // VISIBLE
        public Boolean getVisible() {
            if (null != this.visible) {
                return this.visible;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("visible");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (Boolean) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setVisible(boolean visible){
            this.visible = visible;
        }

        // NAME
        public String getName() {
            if (null != this.name) {
                return this.name;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("name");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        // SUB MENU
        public List<SubMenu> getSubMenu() {
            return this.subMenu;
        }

        public void addSubMenu(SubMenu child){
            if(subMenu==null){
                subMenu = new ArrayList<SubMenu>();
            }
            subMenu.add(child);
        }

        @Override   
        public void restoreState(FacesContext _context, Object _state) {
            Object _values[] = (Object[]) _state;
            super.restoreState(_context, _values[0]);
            this.id = (String) _values[1];
            this.icon = (String) _values[2];
            this.link = (String) _values[3];
            this.visible = (Boolean) _values[4];
            this.name = (String) _values[5];
            this.target = (String) _values[6];
            this.subMenu = StateHolderUtil.restoreList(_context, getComponent(), _values[5]);               
        }

        @Override
        public Object saveState(FacesContext _context) {
            Object _values[] = new Object[8];
            _values[0] = super.saveState(_context);
            _values[1] = id;        
            _values[2] = icon;        
            _values[3] = link;
            _values[4] = visible;
            _values[5] = name;
            _values[6] = target;
            _values[7] = StateHolderUtil.saveList(_context, subMenu);

            return _values;
        }   

}

// COMPLEX SUBMENU.JAVA

package com.forte.complex;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.el.ValueBinding;
import com.ibm.xsp.complex.ValueBindingObjectImpl;

public class SubMenu extends ValueBindingObjectImpl  {
        private String id;
        private String link;
        private Boolean visible;
        private String name;
        private String target;

        public SubMenu() {
        }

        // ID
        public String getId() {
            if (null != this.id) {
                return this.id;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("id");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setId(String id){
            this.id = id;
        }

        // LINK
        public String getLink() {
            if (null != this.link) {
                return this.link;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("link");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setLink(String link){
            this.link = link;
        }

        // VISIBLE
        public Boolean getVisible() {
            if (null != this.visible) {
                return this.visible;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("visible");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (Boolean) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setVisible(boolean visible){
            this.visible = visible;
        }

        // TARGET
        public String getTarget() {
            if (null != this.target) {
                return this.target;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("target");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setTarget(String target){
            this.target = target;
        }


        // NAME
        public String getName() {
            if (null != this.name) {
                return this.name;
            }
            ValueBinding _vb = getValueBinding("name");
            if (_vb != null) {
                return (String) _vb.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            }
            return null;
        }   
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override   
        public void restoreState(FacesContext _context, Object _state) {
            Object _values[] = (Object[]) _state;
            super.restoreState(_context, _values[0]);
            this.id = (String) _values[1];
            this.link = (String) _values[2];
            this.visible = (Boolean)_values[3];
            this.target = (String) _values[4];
            this.name = (String) _values[5];
        }

        @Override
        public Object saveState(FacesContext _context) {
            Object _values[] = new Object[6];
            _values[0] = super.saveState(_context);
            _values[1] = id;
            _values[2] = link;
            _values[3] = visible;
            _values[4] = target;
            _values[5] = name;
            return _values;
        }   

}

<faces-config>
  <faces-config-extension>
    <namespace-uri>http://fortedynamic.org/xsp/control</namespace-uri>
    <default-prefix>forte</default-prefix>
  </faces-config-extension>

  <component>
    <description>Forte Navigation</description>
    <display-name>Navigation</display-name>
    <component-type>com.forte.Navigation</component-type>
    <component-class>com.forte.component.ForteNavigation</component-class>
    <component-extension>
      <component-family>com.forte.Navigation</component-family>
      <renderer-type>com.forte.Navigation</renderer-type>
      <tag-name>navigation</tag-name>
        <designer-extension>
         <in-palette>true</in-palette>
         <category>Forte Smart UI</category>
                 <render-markup>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&#xd;
&lt;xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xp_1="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"&gt;&#xd;  
    &lt;xp:radioGroup layout="&lt;%=
      this.navigation=='left'?'pageDirection':'lineDirection'
    %&gt;"  style="width:155px;height:27px" &gt;    
    &lt;xp:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;%=
      this.navigation=='left'?'Left Navigation':' '
    %&gt;" &gt;&lt;/xp:selectItem&gt;
    &lt;xp:selectItem itemLabel=" "&gt;&lt;/xp:selectItem&gt;
    &lt;xp:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;%=
      this.navigation=='left'?' ':'Top Navigation'
    %&gt;" &gt;&lt;/xp:selectItem&gt;

    &lt;/xp:radioGroup&gt;
&lt;/xp:view&gt;</render-markup>
        </designer-extension>
    </component-extension>

<property>
  <description>Navigation</description>
  <display-name>Navigation</display-name>
  <property-name>navigation</property-name>
  <property-class>string</property-class>
  <property-extension>
    <designer-extension>
      <category>forte</category>
      <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
      <editor-parameter>top&#xd;
      left&#xd;
      </editor-parameter>
    </designer-extension>
  </property-extension>
</property>

<property>
    <description>Menu</description>
    <display-name>Menu</display-name>
    <property-name>menu</property-name>
    <property-class>java.util.List</property-class>
    <property-extension>
        <allow-run-time-binding>false</allow-run-time-binding>
        <collection-property>true</collection-property>
        <property-item-class>com.forte.complex.Menu</property-item-class>
        <property-add-method>addMenu</property-add-method>
        <designer-extension>
            <category>forte</category>
       </designer-extension>
    </property-extension>
</property>

  </component>


<complex-type>
    <description>Menu</description>
    <display-name>Menu</display-name>
    <complex-id>com.forte.complex.menu</complex-id>
    <complex-class>com.forte.complex.Menu</complex-class>
    <property-extension>
        <container-class>java.util.Collection</container-class>
        <collection-property>true</collection-property>
      </property-extension> 
    <property>
      <property-name>id</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>      
    <property>
      <property-name>icon</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>link</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>name</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
        <property-name>visible</property-name>
        <property-class>boolean</property-class>
        <property-extension>
          <designer-extension>
            <default-value>true</default-value>
            <editor>com.ibm.std.Boolean</editor>
          </designer-extension>
        </property-extension>
      </property>


     <property>
        <property-name>subMenu</property-name>
        <property-class>java.util.List</property-class>
        <property-extension>
            <allow-run-time-binding>false</allow-run-time-binding>
            <collection-property>true</collection-property>
            <property-item-class>com.forte.complex.SubMenu</property-item-class>
            <property-add-method>addSubMenu</property-add-method>
        </property-extension>
    </property>

    <property>
  <description>Target</description>
  <display-name>Target</display-name>
  <property-name>target</property-name>
  <property-class>string</property-class>
  <property-extension>
    <designer-extension>
      <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
      <editor-parameter>_blank&#xd;
      _self&#xd;
      _parent&#xd;
      _top&#xd;      
      </editor-parameter>
    </designer-extension>
  </property-extension>
</property>


    <complex-extension>
        <tag-name>menu</tag-name>
    </complex-extension>
</complex-type>


<complex-type>
    <description>Sub Menu</description>
    <display-name>Sub Menu</display-name>
    <complex-id>com.forte.complex.submenu</complex-id>
    <complex-class>com.forte.complex.SubMenu</complex-class>
    <property-extension>
        <container-class>java.util.Collection</container-class>
        <collection-property>true</collection-property>
      </property-extension> 
    <property>
      <property-name>id</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>      
    <property>
      <property-name>link</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>
    <property>
      <property-name>name</property-name>
      <property-class>string</property-class>
    </property>      
    <property>
        <property-name>visible</property-name>
        <property-class>boolean</property-class>
        <property-extension>
          <designer-extension>
            <editor>com.ibm.std.Boolean</editor>
            <default-value>true</default-value>
          </designer-extension>
        </property-extension>
      </property>
     <property>
  <description>Target</description>
  <display-name>Target</display-name>
  <property-name>target</property-name>
  <property-class>string</property-class>
  <property-extension>
    <designer-extension>
      <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.comboParameterEditor</editor>
      <editor-parameter>_blank&#xd;
      _self&#xd;
      _parent&#xd;
      _top&#xd;      
      </editor-parameter>
    </designer-extension>
  </property-extension>
</property> 

    <complex-extension>
        <tag-name>subMenu</tag-name>
    </complex-extension>
</complex-type>

</faces-config>
```